# Highlight in html issue with Jekyll/Liquid and pygments

Tags: html, highlight, jekyll, liquid, pygments

I'm using Jekyll with pygments and having an issue using `{% highlight %}` in .html posts. As you can see [**here**](http://iwasasuperhero.com/2011/07/espresso-2-openinespresso/), it is just printing out {% highlight %} yet on my homepage the syntax highlighting works See here: [**iwasasuperhero.**](http://iwasasuperhero.com/)

[Here](https://github.com/jamesfleeting/iwasasuperhero.com/blob/master/index.html) is the code for the index, and the code for the post: [Here](https://github.com/jamesfleeting/iwasasuperhero.com/blob/master/_posts/2011-07-05-espresso-2-openinespresso.html)

I'm not really sure the issue or why it is working on the index but not the post page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems I have figured out my problem. I was using `{{ page.content }}` in my post.html instead of just `{{ content }}`.