# Jekyll is ignoring Liquid tags within posts

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, liquid, pygments

I'm new to **Jekyll**, **Liquid** and **Ruby** as a whole, so sorry if I'm being really stupid. It seems that Jekyll is ignoring any liquid tags with posts (under the _posts directory), which results in output like the following. These posts are all formatted in markdown, and they all have YAML markup within them.

```
{% highlight scss %} .noisy { @include noise(#00f); } {% endhighlight %}
```

I've tested that it isn't just **Pygments** failing by adding `{{ post.title }}` which is also left unparsed. [Check out the code on Github](https://github.com/nathggns/Blog/tree/design)

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It seems I have figured out my problem. I was using `{{ page.content }}` in
>   my post.html instead of just `{{ content }}`.

[Highlight in html issue with Jekyll/Liquid and pygments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8863058/highlight-in-html-issue-with-jekyll-liquid-an)

---

It's `page.title`

[Template Data · mojombo/jekyll Wiki](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/template-data)

Comment: Using `{{ content }}` seems to have fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure why that isn't working. Does you're for loop work correctly in index.html?

This might be helpful: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers

Comment: The loop is working completely fine. It's really weird, it's as if Liquid is just ignoring it.

Comment: I had (what seemed like) an identical problem with my 404 page with Octopress. Finally, found out that I was trying to use a tag that didn't exist. Does anything else render on the page?

Comment: No, even with things like `{{ site.url }}`, it's just left untouched.